# Load new web page without reloading loading scripts errors

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I Am trying to make a web app load new pages without reloading in the browser. Some pages work fine while other raise errors since scripts are not loaded. The following code is the one to load a new page

```
function loadPage(target, savePushState){ 
        $(".page-content").fadeOut(function(){
             $('body').load(target, function(data) { 
                $(".page-content").fadeIn(function(){
                     var newTitle = $(data).filter('title').text();
                     document.title = newTitle; 
                    if(savePushState){
                        var obj = { Title: newTitle, Url: target };
                        window.history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
                    }                     
                });
             });
        });
            
    }
```

The page links with remote scripts specifically datatbles.net occasionally don't work.
Any tweaks to make it run smooth please.

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"? Do you mean the content you're loading has dependencies on scripts that are not being loaded?

Comment: To be specific. the page has a data table that loads data by ajax from the remote. The tables don't load, a datatable unidentified error on the console.

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you've got is you haven't really thought about dependency management. You've got an elegant way of changing page, but no method to handle the requirements of those pages in terms of CSS/JS.

There's various tutorials and even frameworks that manage this sort of thing. One thing you could do is to declare each valid route's (i.e. page's) dependencies up front, and then load them when you call the route.

Since your loaded HTML seems to depend on JS before it can properly appear, we'll force the insertion of the HTML to wait for any and all JS dependencies to load.

```
const routes = {
    'page1.html': {
        js: ['https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js'],
        css: ['https://guidecore.xyz/assets/css/main.css']
    }
    /* ... */
};

const pageContent = $('.page-content'); //<-- let's cache this element
function loadPage(target, savePushState) {
    pageContent.fadeOut(function() {

        //let's load dependencies
        const promises = [];
        ['js', 'css'].forEach(type => {
            routes[target] && (routes[target][type] ?? []).forEach(uri => {
                if (type == 'js')
                    promises.push(fetch(uri)
                        .then(response => response.text())
                        .then(code => {
                            const el = document.createElement('script');
                            el.textContent = code;
                            document.body.appendChild(el);
                        })
                    );
                else {
                    const el = document.createElement('link');
                    el.href = uri;
                    el.rel = 'stylesheet';
                    document.head.appendChild(el);
                }
            });
        });

        //wait for JS dependencies to load before we get new HTML
        Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
            $('body').load(target, function(data) { 
                pageContent.fadeIn(function(){
                    let newTitle = $(data).filter('title').text();
                    document.title = newTitle; 
                    if(savePushState) {
                        var obj = { Title: newTitle, Url: target };
                        window.history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
                    }                     
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
loadPage('page1.html');
```